# Linear mapping $\mathbb{N_0}\times\mathbb{N_0}\to \mathbb{N_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $L(m,n)=am+bn+c$ mapping $\mathbb{N_0}\times\mathbb{N_0}$ to $\mathbb{N_0}$, not a constant. We see that $L(0,0)=c$ is necessarily integer. The same true of $a=L(1,0)-c$ and $b=L(0,1)-c$. In fact, $a$ and $b$ must be nonnegative integers, not both zero.

I have understood everything, except that $a,b\geqslant 0$.

Can anyone explain how to derive that?

Comment: Suppose $a<0$ and consider $L(m,0)$ for sufficiently large $m$. Is $L(m,0)$ in $\mathbb{N}_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a < 0$

Then $L(m,0) = am + c  \ge 0$

So $c \ge -am = |a|m$ and $\frac c{|a|} \ge m$ for all $m\in \mathbb N$.  But $\frac c{|a|}$ is a constant and the naturals are unbounded so that is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ to be defined, we have to make sure that be sure that for every $a \in A, \ f(a) \in B$. In other words,  $Im(f) \subseteq B $.

Now, in your problem, it's necessary that $a,b \geq 0,$ else we could find that for some $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N_0} \times \mathbb{N_0}, \ $  $L (x,y) \notin \mathbb{N_0}$.

For example, consider $a=-3 , b=-2 $ and $c = 4$. Now consider the element $(1,1) \in \mathbb{N_0} \times \mathbb{N_0}$ and then

$$L(1,1) = -3(1) + (-2)(1) + c = -5 + 4 = -1 $$

Notice that $-1 \notin \mathbb{N_0}$ .

Comment: Nice interpretation!

Answer (score 0):

To derive this check that 0 < L(m,0) = am + c which proves that a is positive.
otherwise we can find an m such that am + c < 0/